# How to destructure an array with object that has space in its keys?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, map-function

```
data={data.map(({ ID,filePath,accountId,companyId,['First Name'], ...rest }) => rest)}
```

In this case First Name is a key with space, apparently when passed as above it causes error. How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Variable names (identifiers) can't have spaces in them, you won't be able to destructure that property into a standalone variable *unless* you also rename the variable - which can be done using bracket notation:

```
data.map(({
  ID,
  filePath,
  accountId,
  companyId,
  ['First Name']: firstName,
  ...rest
}) => rest)
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    'First Name': 'foo',
    'anotherProp': 'another'
  },
  {
    'First Name': 'bar',
    'anotherProp': 'another'
  }
];

const mapped = data.map(({
  ID,
  filePath,
  accountId,
  companyId,
  ['First Name']: firstName,
  ...rest
}) => rest);

console.log(mapped);
```